# List Preferences is returning Entries and not EntryValues

Tags: android, preferences, listpreference

I created a List Preference in my Preferences Activity and the value that the code is returning for the selected item is the value of the Entry and not the value of the EntryValues.

**Example:**
Entry: *David New*
Value: *DAVIDNEW.TTF*

The codes returns "*David New*" instead of "*DAVIDNEW.TTF*".

---

Here's the code:

File `preferences.xml`:

```
<ListPreference
            android:key="fontSelect"
            android:title="@string/textPrefs"
            android:summary="@string/textPrefs"
            android:defaultValue="DAVIDNEW.TTF"
            android:entries="@array/fonts"
            android:entryValues="@array/fontsValues" />
```

File `arrays.xml`:

```
<string-array name="fonts">
    <item>Alex</item>
    <item>Cardo</item>
    <item>Chaya</item>
    <item>David New</item>
    <item>Droid Sans</item>
    <item>Frank</item>
    <item>Mike Hebrew</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="fontsValues">
    <item>ALEX.TTF</item>
    <item>Cardo99s.ttf</item>
    <item>CHAYA.TTF</item>
    <item>DAVIDNEW.TTF</item>
    <item>DroidSansHebrew.ttf</item>
    <item>frank.ttf</item>
    <item>mike_hebrew_regular_v33.ttf</item>
</string-array>
```

File `reader.java`:

```
String f1 = new String(myprefs.getString("fontSelect", "DAVIDNEW.TTF"));
font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), f1);
tv.setTypeface(font);
```

Value of `f1` is "*David New*" instead of "*DAVIDNEW.TTF*".

Comment: Same problem for me...

Comment: I've seen that running on the emulator, it was returning "entries", while running on a device it was returning "entryValues". Seems a bug so far...

Comment: It could be returning that value because the instance of ListPreference has associated programatically a setOnPreferenceChangeListener that is returning false in the onPreferenceChange method instead of true, so the entryValue is not being updated in the default SharedPreferences.

Have a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html